# Allow user interaction during performBatchUpdates

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation, tvos

I have a collection view which I modify it's item's size, I apply the change by calling it's `performBatchUpdates` method.

This causes the change to happen using a nice animation, the thing is, it also disables all user interaction with my collectionView, which I would like to still be allowed.

I've also tried wrapping the call inside a `UIView.animate` block with `.allowUserInteraction` option, with no luck.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
     workItem?.cancel()
     workItem = DispatchWorkItem(block: {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
             self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
         }, completion: nil)
    })

     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: workItem!)
}
```

Is there any way to get past that and allow user interaction during the animation?

Comment: User interaction on a collection view that is in the middle of being animated sounds incoherent. What's your real goal?

Comment: I'm on tvOS, I have a collection view which I want its items to change size when focused, While I do achieve this effect using the code above (and some code in `sizeForItemAt`), but I do not want to block the user from interacting with the app while this happens so the user will be able to keep scrolling even while one of the cell is changing it's size.

Answer (score 0):

If workItem is heavy you could try to move it to a background thread. From my experience, updating/making changes in UICollectionView while doing something on the main thread always freezes UI.

You can try :

```
   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
     workItem! 
    }
```

Comment: I cannot do this as `workItem` is touching GUI elements, which is only possible through the gui thread.